# What is the word for the primary piece of literature on a subject

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

The word I'm looking for describes a piece of literature/media well-known among members of a certain profession/practice as the bible of their trade. For example, *A Twist of the Wrist* by Keith Code is well-known among motorcycle riders as the go-to resource for a beginner learning to ride a motorcycle.

Comment: Since this is on hold, I can't answer, but I would add "definitive" as an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canonical is usually used in this context.

***[Canonical:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/canonical)***

> Accepted as being accurate and authoritative.

***[Authoritative](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/authoritative)*** fits well also:

> (of a text) considered to be the best of its kind and unlikely to be
> improved upon.

-- Both definitions taken from Oxford Dictionaries.

Comment: My pleasure, Carlo!